# How do I display a running total for averages and for counting each entry?

Tags: c#

I have a program that you type in your name and a score out of 150. It correctly displays the letter grade and percentage. The problem is it won't keep a running total of the number of submissions 1,2,3,... nor does that average running total work. It just displays the same data as the percentage.
How do I fix these?

Code:

```
private void CalculateButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        decimal Score = 0 , Percent, Average = 0, Sum;
        string Letter = "";
        int GrandTotal = 0;

        Score = decimal.Parse(ScoreTextBox.Text);

        if (NameTextBox.Text != "" && ScoreTextBox.Text != "")
        {
            if (Score >= 0 && Score <= 150)
            {
                
                Percent = Score / 150;
                if (Percent >= .90M)
                    Letter = "A";
                else if (Percent >= .80M && Percent < .90M)
                    Letter = "B";
                else if (Percent >= .70M && Percent < .80M)
                    Letter = "C";
                else if (Percent >= .60M && Percent < .70M)
                    Letter = "D";
                else if (Percent < .60M)
                    Letter = "E";

                GrandTotal += 1;
                Sum = GrandTotal;
                Average += Percent + Average / (Sum * 150); 


                PercentTextBox.Text = Percent.ToString("P");
                LetterGradeTextBox.Text = Letter;
                GrandTotalTextBox.Text = GrandTotal.ToString();
                AverageTextBox.Text = Average.ToString("P");
            }
            else
                MessageBox.Show("Score must be a positive number between 0 - 150");

        }
        else
            MessageBox.Show("Name and a Score between 0 - 150 are required");
    }
}
```

Comment: You are defining your variables in the beginning of the mehod, which means you're never adding more than one single score together. `Average`, `Sum` etc. are always reset to 0 in the beginning of the method. You probably want to define those variables in the class scope

Comment: Please mark the answer if it was a solution for you or provide comments so we can help further.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution using a list to track the scores then perform the operations on list.  Notice the list declared above the void.

```
   private readonly List<decimal> scores = new List<decimal>();

    private void CalculateButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        decimal score = decimal.Parse(ScoreTextBox.Text);
        string Letter = "";

        if (NameTextBox.Text != "" && ScoreTextBox.Text != "")
        {
            if (score >= 0 && score <= 150)
            {
                scores.Add(score);

                decimal Percent = score / 150;
                if (Percent >= .90M)
                    Letter = "A";
                else if (Percent >= .80M && Percent < .90M)
                    Letter = "B";
                else if (Percent >= .70M && Percent < .80M)
                    Letter = "C";
                else if (Percent >= .60M && Percent < .70M)
                    Letter = "D";
                else if (Percent < .60M)
                    Letter = "E";

                PercentTextBox.Text = Percent.ToString("P");
                LetterGradeTextBox.Text = Letter;
                GrandTotalTextBox.Text = scores.Count.ToString();
                AverageTextBox.Text = (scores.Average() / 150).ToString("P");
            }
            else
                MessageBox.Show("Score must be a positive number between 0 - 150");

        }
        else
            MessageBox.Show("Name and a Score between 0 - 150 are required");
    }
}
```